# Finding (or setting) the y-value of the bottom of draw curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-positioning

I have the following image code which works great for what I need. I've cut a ton of the drawing out to just focus on the piece that I need (it's a graduated cylinder with increment markings in the full version).

```
\documentclass[convert, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\standaloneconfig{tikz}
\tikzset{x=5in, y=5in}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\gradcylinder}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\numLabels{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\minorSpace{#3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\majorSpace{\fpeval{\minorSpace*5}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\majorTBGap{\fpeval{\majorSpace/2}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\height{\fpeval{2*\majorTBGap+\majorSpace*((\numLabels*2)-2)}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\waterHeight{#1*\height}
    \draw (1, 0) rectangle (1.2, \height);
        \fill[cyan, fill opacity=0.4] (1, 0) to (1, \waterHeight) to [out=-30, in=210, looseness=0.8] (1.2, \waterHeight) to (1.2, 0);
    \draw[densely dashed] (1.1, \waterHeight-0.02378) -- (1.2, \waterHeight-0.02378);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\gradcylinder{0.8}{2}{0.02}
\end{document}
```

#1 is how far up the shaded curve starts as a percent of the total height. I have 2 goals that I don't know how to do:

1. I'd like to be able to define the bottom of the shaded curve for the dotted line (rather than my hacked -0.02378), but I'm not sure how to calculate that value or figure it out to use a node position to draw the dotted line
2. I'd love to be able to change value of #1 to be the percent height that sets the bottom of the curve instead of where the tops start. I'm wondering if there is a similar way to draw the curve that has this point set.

I hope those goals are clear, but please let me know if not.

Comment: 1. Add `coordinate[midway](@)` after the `to` that produces the curve, then the dashed line can be drawn as `\draw[densely dashed] (@) -- (1.2, 0|-@);`. (`midway` is also default but in case your whole document changes that …) 2. If I understand this correctly, you want `\waterHeight` to be the height of said `@` point and then draw the curve above that point. Does the height of this curve matter? It needs to come from somewhere. Now, it comes from the curve.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel you understand question #2 correctly. It's probably a trivial point to worry about (since they are so close), but I would like to be able to say "set the bottom of the curve at 60%" and then create the graphic. Instead of now saying "set the left/right edges of the curve at 60%". Thank you for the midway position, of course, so simple :)